¿Por qué funciona mi código?
Me encuentro aprendiendo JavaScript, el siguiente código está escrito en ese lenguaje y en el VisualStudioCode
function isParBolean(num) {
   if (num % 2 == 0) {
    console.log("es par")
   } else {
    console.log("es impar")
   }
 }
isParBolean(50)

Consulta: me gustaría saber si el código funciona porqué el "0" lo toma como un resultado de número entero o existe otra razón. Gracias!

Por definición el cero es par. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paridad_del_cero#:~:text=El%200%20es%20par.,%2C%200%20%3D%200%20%C3%97%202.

El operador % devuelve el módulo es decir el resto o residuo de la divisiónm entera. Al ser el segundo argumento un 2 los dos únicos posibles resultados son 0 si es par o 1 si es impar.

El código funciona sin problema, en este caso estás usando el operador %.
Lo que realiza en esta operación
num % 2 == 0

indica que que si num es divisible entre 2 sin dejar residuo, o sea 0, el número es par, de otra forma es impar. En realidad el 0 es considerado un número par, revisa Paridad del cero.
Revisa este ejemplo basado en tu código:
function isParBolean(num) {
   if (num % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(num,"es par");
   } else {
    console.log(num, "es impar");
   }
 }
 
isParBolean(0);
isParBolean(1);
isParBolean(2);
isParBolean(3);
isParBolean(4);
isParBolean(5);

Salida:
0 es par
1 es impar
2 es par
3 es impar
4 es par
5 es impar

